# What does - mean when querying

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I came across a certain query and I am not able to figure out what exactly it does:

```
parkSchema.statics.findAllParkSlots = function(params, callback){
    return this.findById(params.park_location_id, '-_id slots').exec(callback);
}
```

Any idea what does `-` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) is not a MongoDB function, but comes from the Mongoose library (assuming you are using that one).

The first parameter is the `_id`, the second one defines the projection (which fields to select): You name the fields you want, or you prefix the fields with `-` that you don't want. In this case "`slots` and not `_id`" (which is otherwise always included, even if not explicitly mentioned).

Comment: well thanks but this querry is returning me slots and you are saying that     '-_id slots' should exclude slots. Please correct me here.

Comment: No. `"-_id"` excludes `_id` and `"slots"` includes `slots`.